# Kill all process which uses specified port on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, port, ubuntu-14.04, amazon-ec2

What's the reason the process is still alive?

List of node process running and what I tried:

```
root@111:/home/ubuntu# ps -e -o pid,ppid,stat,cmd  | grep node
 3150     1 Ss   sudo /usr/bin/node /home/ubuntu/chatapp/bin/www
 3152  3150 Sl   /usr/bin/node /home/ubuntu/chatapp/bin/www
 4407  1558 S+   grep --color=auto node
root@111:/home/ubuntu# kill -9 3150
root@111:/home/ubuntu# kill -9 3152
root@111:/home/ubuntu# ps -e -o pid,ppid,stat,cmd  | grep node
 4665     1 Ss   sudo /usr/bin/node /home/ubuntu/chatapp/bin/www
 4667  4665 Sl   /usr/bin/node /home/ubuntu/chatapp/bin/www
 4680  1558 S+   grep --color=auto node
```

Comment: How did you start the process, via forever, pm2, upstart, monit, or something similar?

Comment: I used `node app.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$ sudo kill -9 18200
```

Note the added flag '-9', which forces the murder...

From [linus signal(7) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html):

```
...
SIGKILL       9       Term    Kill signal
...
```

Comment: What is the result? process is not killed? Are you really sure the PID you passed to `kill -9` did survive? I'd be REALLY surprised... :-(

Comment: So, the processes you killed (`3150`, `3152`) are dead. Other node processes are born just after the killing. The most probale explanation is you have a process (like `nodemon`, for example), which re-spawns node processes when they die... You sould stop `nodemon`, first... :-)

Comment: I was using forever previously but uninstalled it. Will uninstalling node kill all node processes ?

Comment: No, it wil not. Memory and Filesystem are two different beasts... If you're unsure about the daemons on your system, I'd suggest you to reboot, and then, if node is alive again, better look for the service spawning it...

Comment: I am running this on aws-ec2 instance. I don't think rebooting will help as aws maintains state.

Comment: So you're left with the option to look for the service spawning node on your instance...

Comment: Could you please help me on that?

Comment: Thank you so much :) I was running a upstart service.

Answer (score 0):

You killed process id 18200
You state node is still running, but that's process id 31261, not the one you killed...
Is the remaining process (parent pid = 1) a child proces that's been orphaned by killing 18200?

Comment: Tried `kill -9 1`. Node state still running.

Comment: You can't kill process 1. That's the OS init system.
In your example, kill -9 31261

Comment: Right. So how do I free the port?